# Psychological pricing: reducing theft?

Tags: psychology, criminology, price

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The origin of “99 cents”](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2359/the-origin-of-99-cents)

On Wikipedia, the article for [psychological pricing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_pricing) (ending prices in -99 or similar) gives the following suggestion for why it is done, as opposed to the psychological aspect behind it.

> Others have suggested that fractional
>   pricing was first adopted as a control
>   on employee theft. For cash
>   transactions with a round price, there
>   is a chance that a dishonest cashier
>   will pocket the bill rather than
>   record the sale. For cash transactions
>   with an odd price, the cashier must
>   make change for the customer. This
>   generally means opening the cash
>   register which creates a record of the
>   sale in the register and reduces the
>   risk of the cashier stealing from the
>   store owner.

This is not cited or sourced, so I wonder if any studies have been performed on this? Is it actually harder to steal from the store with odd prices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Psychological Pricing: Private vs. Professional Vendors](http://www.econ.kuleuven.be/tem/jaargangen/2001-2010/2008/RBE%202008-4/2008-4%20-%20Van%20Caneghem.pdf)

> While it has been argued that psychological pricing was originally introduced as an
>   aid to prevent theft by employees (Gendall et al., 1996), it is nowadays common
>   belief that psychological prices boost sales

You can find the quoted paper behind paywalls here:

http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=1185497659407632930&hl=de&as_sdt=0,5

In [PRICE POINTS AND PRICE RIGIDITY ON THE INTERNET: A MASSIVE QUASI-EXPERIMENTAL DATA MINING APPROACH](http://www.misrc.umn.edu/workingpapers/fullpapers/2005/0512_050605.pdf)

> Historically, odd pricing was developed to control 
>   employee theft from cash registers, by requiring change to be given to the customer so the sale 
>   was recorded.

In [$9.99: CAN "JUST-BELOW" PRICING BE RECONCILED WITH REALITY](http://www.jstor.org/pss/40325699)

> The cash register made it easier for store owners to prevent employee theft since it kept a record of each transaction rung up by the employee. However, the employee could still pocket the money and not ring up the sale.