# Are prices ending with 99 cents more likely to result in purchase decisions?

Tags: psychology, economics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The origin of “99 cents”](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2359/the-origin-of-99-cents)

["Psychological pricing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_pricing) refers to the theory that certain prices are more likely to lead to a sale than others. In the United States, that price is usually 99 cents - it is far more common to see a product priced at $5.99 than it is to see a product priced at $6.00. Theoretically, therefore, customers are more likely to purchase a $5.99 product than to purchase a $6.00 product.  I wonder if this is actually true.

**Are consumers more likely to make a purchase if the price ends in x.99 rather than x.00?  And if not, why do products continue to be priced this way?**

Comment: They **are** lower, by one cent.

Comment: Another user edited the title in a way that did not reflect my actual question.  I don't care about how the prices are perceived, I care about whether they cause more purchase decisions.

Comment: @SteveV.: if they caused more purchase decisions it would be because they would be perceived as lower.

Comment: Closed as the other question is a tad more general. It has good answers and they do apply here.